# Only the first page of react-route is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

this is my second using stackflow, so sorry if something is hard to understand, I'm creating a React project, and when I put the Route, only the first page is rendered, and no more, my site is practically One Page , only one page is not the About Page.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/Cardapio" element={<Cardapio />} />
        <Route exact path="/Knowmore" element={<Knowmore />} />
        <Route exact path="/About" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<p>Página não encontrada</p>} />
      </Routes>   
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I see 4 explicit individual routes and a 5th "catch-all" route. They should all render individually when their path matches. What are you expecting to render and when? Are you saying when you navigate to the other routes that the UI isn't updating?

Comment: I want all pages to appear since it's practically One Page, I just want to scroll down to get to the sessions, but in the last session called "Knowmore" there is a button, on this button when I click I want to open a new page that will be the "About", I'm already using useNavigate on the button and target _Blank, the problem is that as it's only rendering the first Page of the Route, ie the "Home".

Comment: Then all the components you want on one "page" should all be rendered on the same route. Use raw anchor tags to link to hash identifiers on the page.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: What is your react version?

Comment: react version 18.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render several of the components together on the same route they should all be combined and merged on the same path.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <>
        <Home />
        <Cardapio />
        <Knowmore />
      </>
    }
  />
  <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<p>Página não encontrada</p>} />
</Routes>
```

If you are wanting to link to the individual components, i.e. home, cardapio, and know more "sections", then assign appropriate element `id` attributes to them and target them with rendered raw anchor tags.

Basic example:

```
const Home = () => (
  <div id="home">
    Home
  </div>
);

const Cardapio = () => (
  <div id="cardapio">
    Cardapio
  </div>
);

const Knowmore = () => (
  <div id="knowmore">
    Knowmore
  </div>
);
```

Nav links in `App`:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#cardapio">Cardapio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#knowmore">Know More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: Edit only-the-first-page-of-react-route-is-rendered]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
         <Route index element={<Home />} />
         <Route path="Cardapio" element={<Cardapio />} />
         <Route path="Knowmore" element={<Knowmore />} />
         <Route path="About" element={<About/>} />
         <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

if it is not working, please let me know. It can be related with react version **v17** or **v18**

Comment: shows this : "You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app."

Comment: Like I pointed out in one of the other answers, if OP was missing a router there'd be a bunch of invariant errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the content with `<BrowserRouter>` tag.

Comment: If OP wasn't rendering the routes within a router component they would likely be asking about a bunch of invariant errors. Instead the routes ***are*** rendering content, but just not the content OP wants. I don't believe this is the issue.